# How to split a string by multiple delimiters and also store it in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, split

I need to split a string by multiple delimiters.
My string is `HELLO+WORLD-IT*IS=AMAZING`.

I would like the result be
`["HELLO", "+", "WORLD", "-", "IT", "*", "IS", "=", "AMAZING"`

I hear that re.findall() may handle it but I can't find out the solution.

Comment: `re.split(r'\b', ur_string)[1:-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
s='HELLO+WORLD-IT*IS=AMAZING'
```

You can split on any break between a word and non word character as a general case with the [word boundary assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`:

```
>>> re.split(r'\b', s)
['', 'HELLO', '+', 'WORLD', '-', 'IT', '*', 'IS', '=', 'AMAZING', '']
```

And remove the `''` at the start and end like so:

```
>>> re.split(r'\b', ur_string)[1:-1]
['HELLO', '+', 'WORLD', '-', 'IT', '*', 'IS', '=', 'AMAZING']
```

Or if you know that is the full set of delimiters that you want to use for a split, define a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) of them and capture the delimiter:

```
>>> re.split(r'([+\-*=])', s)
['HELLO', '+', 'WORLD', '-', 'IT', '*', 'IS', '=', 'AMAZING']
```

Since `\b` is a zero width assertion (it does not consume characters to match) you don't have to capture what the delimiter was that caused the split. The assertion of `\b` is also true at the start and end of the string so those blanks need to be removed.

Since `-` is used in a character class to define a range of characters such as `[0-9]` you have to escape the `-` in `[+\-*=]`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.split` works in this case. Put every delimiter in a capturing group:

```py
    pattern = "(\+|-|\*|=)"
    result = re.split(pattern, string)
```